# 1 to many relationship in OOP PHP in code?

Tags: class, oop, uml, diagram

[image: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/assets/img/uml-order.png]

This is the class diagram implemented, but what would a 1-to-many relationship look like in code?

This is a text please stackoverflow accept my question

```
class Customer {

    public $name;
    public $location;

    public function sendOrder(){
            //method here
    }

    public function receiveOrder(){
            //method here
    }

}

class Order {
    public $date;
    public $number;

    public function sendOrder(){
            //method here
    }

        public function receiveOrder(){
            //method here
        }
    }

class SpecialOrder Extends Order{
    public function dispatch(){
        //method here
    }
}

class NormalOrder Extends Order{
    public function dispatch(){
        //method here
    }

    public function receive(){
        //method here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class diagram does not force any implementation for multiplicity. So you are free on how to implement it. The easiest most forward is an array of `Order` inside `Customer`. My PHP is quite rusted, but it would probably look like this:

```
class Customer {
  $orders = []; // references to orders
  // rest of the class
}
```